# Application crash on exit

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

i have the following problem: I am programming a little modding tool for a game, and everything works just fine. But when i'm compiling it static, with Qt built static, it crashes when im closing the application. This does not happen when im compiling it with the standard Qt dynamic libraries.

So what am i doing wrong? Here is the output of the gdb, im having:

[image]

I would appreciate any help. If you need any part of my code, just say it. I'm actually not sure here, which part of my code i should post!

Thanks

Edit: It appears that the problem is in the buildchain. I built the libraries with the same configuration except the -static. Is my error somewhere in there?

configure -release  -nomake examples -nomake demos -no-qt3support -no-scripttools -no-openssl -no-opengl -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-style-motif -no-style-cde -no-style-cleanlooks -no-style-plastique -no-sql-sqlite

Comment: Getting Qt to work statically is very difficult, it's just not designed for that. Any reason why you cannot use the dynamic libraries?

Comment: Its just a convinience issue. It is easier to distribute one .exe, instead of a couple of files... but im considering dynamic libraries.

Did you have similar problems?

Comment: it's true it would be nice if Qt made it easier to distribute just one exe, but unfortunately they don't. I tried to compile statically on Windows and Mac but never managed to get it work properly. In the end, we just used the dynamic libraries.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. It pretty much works as designed. Webkit doesn't work, and IIRC that's about it. There are complex Qt apps that are distributed as a self-contained, statically linked executable.